# Improve the speed of code in an excel addin using C# and vsto

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Currently, I am developing an excel addin using C# and vsto. One of the function is to round the value of all selected cells to the nearest dollar. The following is the code I have tried to implement and it seems work perfectly with a few cells being selected.

However, when the number of cells being selected is large (eg. the entire col), it takes a huge of time to do the job. I would like to ask if there are any ways to improve the efficiency of the code.

```
        Excel.Application ExApp = Globals.Helper.Application as Excel.Application;


        Excel.Worksheet ExWorksheet = ExApp.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;

        Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range)ExApp.ActiveCell;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range selectedRange =
            ExApp.ActiveWindow.RangeSelection;

        foreach (Excel.Range r in selectedRange.Cells)
        {
            if(r.Formula!=null)
            {
            string v = r.Formula.Replace("=", "");
            r.Formula = "=Round(" + v + ",0)";}
        }
```

Comment: Sorry to poke a hole in the entire concept but can you not do this already in Excel using format cells.

Comment: VSTO is very slow: I suggest you switch to Excel DNA http://excel-dna.net/

Comment: @CharlesWilliams do u have any idea or example showing hot to use Excel DNA to achieve the above work